# local database will not deploy to Azure

Tags: azure

I am new to Azure & have searched everywhere but here for help. I have a local MVC 5 app w/ simple database. I am using VS 2015 Community w/ all updates.
Problem: Using visual studio, my web app works perfectly in Azure, BUT my local database will not deploy. The db works perfect locally, but when I deploy, only the web app shows up...the database is not there in Azure. I get a generic message saying "There was an error processing your request". I have tried creating the db in Azure and connecting w/ no luck. Everything but the database deploys. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks, everybody.
Jeff

Comment: What exactly do you get when creating the database directly in azure? should be pretty straight forward. If it's sql server, you can also use local management studio to export the data-tier. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-cloud-migrate/

Comment: When I try to use SSMS, I only have the option to use copy to a VM. I am using a Pay As You Go Subscription and using Azure Sql Server. I keep trying, but  my DB will not deploy. I don't wanna give up .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not deploy the database in Azure. Instead, you create a database in Azure, and then, under deployment, you point your app's connectionstring to that instead.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Still no luck. Here is where I am now:   I completely deleted my Resource Group(nothing there)--- I made a new Resource Group--- I created a new sql server--- then I made a new Sql Server Database--- I did not make a new WebApp yet.                               Question: Should I use the publish option in Visual Studio? Or make a New WebApp in Azure? I'm getting frustrated and confused. Thanks a million for any help.

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion put me on the right track and I'm up and running now.